# Terminal problems entering password

Tags: command-line, gnome, password, sudo

Every time I try to enable shell theme extension or anything in general in Terminal it asks me for a password but won't accept it.

Answer (score 3):

When you are asked for your password in the Terminal, no placeholder characters (like `*`) appear as you enter it. That's not a problem--just type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your password is being received. The reason nothing is echoed back to you is for security--so that people looking at the screen (or at a log from the Terminal) don't know how many characters your password is.

If you enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it tells you that it's wrong, then make sure that <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> was not on when you entered it. Make sure that you're putting in the password appropriate to the task--in the Terminal, when you are prompted for a password, this is almost always your user password, that is, the password you'd use to log in and/or unlock the screen. (If you ran a command in the Terminal that started with `sudo`, then it is definitely your user password.) Your user password is not necessarily the same as your keyring password. (Also, you might not have a keyring password, but you certainly have a user password.)

If you do not remember your password, you can reset it using [this technique](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword).